# Antd - Table save sorting in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using [Antd Version 4.2.2.](https://ant.design/) in ReactJS.

and the < Table /> component.

What I want to achieve is: Save the sorting order that is set in the columns to redux.

My approach is:

```js
const onChangeSorting = (dataIndex, sortingVal) => {
  dispatchFns.setConfig(['sortOrder-', dataIndex].join(''), sortingVal);
};

const columns = [{
  title: ({
    sortOrder,
    sortColumn
  }) => {
    if (sortOrder && sortColumn) {
      onChangeSorting(sortOrder, sortColumn);
    }
    return 'Stellentitel';
  },
  dataIndex: 'title',
  render: renderCell,
  sorter: (a, b) => a.title.length - b.title.length,
  sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend'],
}];
```

But of course I get the error:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.
```

And also get the erro:

```
 Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

What Function can I use for storing the sorting type into redux ?

I could not find the matching antd function to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The `onChange` props defined at the table level is called whenever the sorting or filtering changes. Therefore:

```
<Table
    onChange={(pagination, filters, sorter, {currentDataSource}) => {
        dispatchFns.setConfig(`sortOrder-${sorter.field}`, sorter.order);
    }}
/>
```